# Changing size and position of a window belonging to another process

Tags: c#, winapi

I have a compiled c# console application and I would like to have an option to change a certain window (*.exe from, lets say, task manager) position and size.
Is it possible via the namespaces provided in VS2010?
The target window isn't connected in any way to the exe compiled by VS.

Comment: I'd imagine its all possible from the `SetWindowPos` function and a few other things, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, you definitely have to use the [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

You will need the window handle. For this you could call [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), checking the executable file name for each window using [GetWindowModuleFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633517%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Pseudo code:

```
foreach window in EnumWindows()
    if GetWindowModuleFileName(window) == "program.exe"
        SetWindowPos(window, ...)
```

These functions belong to the Windows API. To call them you will need to P/invoke ([pinvoke.net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633517%28VS.85%29.aspx) might be of great help).

Answer (score 2):

It's quite possible:

1. To change window position or/and size you may use *SetWindowPos*

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545(v=vs.85).aspx
2. In order find out window's handle (hWnd argument) you may found useful

   *FindWindow*

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499(v=vs.85).aspx

   *EnumWindows*

   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx